Azure devOps not recognising Github Enterprise Service Connections for New pipelines whilst works for existing pipelines
Suddenly we getting error today with existing github enterprise service connections using which we created multiple pipelines which are all working but when today we trying to create a new pipeline using Github enterprise service connection it says :

The user doesn't have access to the service connection(s) added to this pipeline or they are not found. Names/IDs: XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX

Whereas the user access is there, Pipeline access is open to all and Moreover existing pipelines are all working still new pipeline setup is throwing above error.
Any clue what's happening here please?
Create a new pipeline with existing github enterprise Service connection.
Considering service connection has all the access it should allow to create pipeline.

Refer to this ticket on Developer Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PROBLEM-WITH-SERVICE-CONNECTIONS-BITBUCK/10662186 This appears to be a recent issue and the developer team is investigating. You can keep monitoring the ticket.

Thanks @KevinLu-MSFT for sharing this. I will monitor it.

The issue should be fixed now. You can try to use the existing service connection to create the pipeline again. Feel free to share the result with us.

Refer to this ticket: PROBLEM WITH SERVICE CONNECTIONS BITBUCKET
This issue is caused by changes in the backend service of the new version of Azure DevOps Service. It will affect the Oauth authentication of service connections such as Github,Bitbucket.
Now, the Azure DevOps Developer team has fixed the issue.
You can use the existing Github Enterprise Service Connections to create the Pipeline now.

This looks like an authorization problem - is the service connection authorized?
To authorize a service connection for this pipeline, open the pipeline by selecting Edit and queue a build manually. You see a resource authorization error and an "Authorize resources" action on the error. Choose this action to explicitly add the pipeline as an authorized user of the service connection.
See Use a service connection for more details.

The pipeline is not created at all so I don't have option to edit it.
